# Is there a way to find the differences between two similar documents in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have made changes to one copy of a document. I also have a copy of the original file. I would like to find out what I have changed. Is there a way to get Word to tell me?

<sub>(I am using Microsoft Word 2003. However, do include answers for other versions, in order to make this question as useful as possible to the community.)</sub>

Comment: Is it essential to use Word to determine the difference?  To track text changes, an easy and accurate method is to copy into and save as 2 .txt files. You can then use VisualDiff, WinMerge or a similar tool to quickly ID changes between those two text files.

Answer (score 3):

The way I found to do this in Word 2003 is:

- Open the recent version
- Turn on "Track Changes" by clicking on Tools / Track Changes
- Go to Tools / Compare and Merge Documents...
- Select the old version
- A new window opens containing the old version with all changes added and highlighted

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this in Word 2010 is:

- Open the two documents you want to compare
- On the Review Tab in the Compare group, select "Compare two versions of a document"
- Fill in the blanks
- The default result is that a third document is created which is the original document with the changes made and highlighted.
- See Word help file under "Compare documents with the legal blackline option"

Comment: Works in 2007 as well.