# Highlighting similar text between two Word files

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, highlighting

I have two Word documents and I want to highlight the text in common on file 2. I have the below macro (which is supposed to highlight any text strings with more than 4 words in common between the documents), but it did not work. (btw, I did replace the file path with the correct path for the second file.)  Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

---

```vba
Sub HighlightCommonWords()
    Dim doc1 As Document
    Dim doc2 As Document
    Dim wrd1 As Range
    Dim wrd2 As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim common As String
    
    Set doc1 = ActiveDocument
    Set doc2 = Documents.Open("path\to\second\file.docx")
    
    For i = 1 To doc1.Words.Count
        Set wrd1 = doc1.Words(i)
        If wrd1.Words.Count > 4 Then
            For j = 1 To doc2.Words.Count
                Set wrd2 = doc2.Words(j)
                If wrd2.Words.Count > 4 Then
                    If wrd1.Text = wrd2.Text Then
                        common = wrd1.Text
                        Do While wrd1.Find.Execute(FindText:=common, MatchCase:=True)
                            wrd1.HighlightColorIndex = wdGray25
                        Loop
                    End If
                End If
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
    
    doc2.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: You can do this [using Word](https://superuser.com/q/219703/)

Comment: Just a starting point. You have "wrd1 = doc1.Words(i)". So that sets wrd1 to be *one* Word object( or possibly Nothing, or something less than 1 Word). But then you have "If wrd1.Words.Count > 4 Then". There's only one word, so the count is never going to be more than 1.

Given time I'd try to dive deeper but hope that will help you progress.